# Question on infinite model

Tags: model-theory

Here is a question in "Lectures on Infinitary Model Theory" by Marker. Let $\tau$ be the vocabulary with constant symbols $d, c_0, c_1,\cdots$ and let $\Gamma$ be the set of sentences
$$
\{d\ne c_i\colon i\in\omega\}\cup\{\forall v\bigvee_{i\in\omega} v=c_i\}
$$
Show that every finite subset of $\Gamma$ is satisfiable, but $\Gamma$ is not satisfiable. Thus the Compactness Theorem fails for infinitary sentences.

I think the first part means that every $c_i$ is not $d$ and the second means that $v$ is any one of $c_i$. But I am not sure how finite subset of $\Gamma$ is satisfiable, while $\Gamma$ is not satisfiable

Comment: The "first sentence" is not a single sentence.  It is a countable collection of sentences.  For example, one sentence in that countable collection is $d \neq c_{376}$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hint:

To see why the entire theory is not satisfiable, think about what you've already written:

> I think the first part means that every $c_i$ is not $d$ and the second means that $v$ is any one of $c_i$.

If every element of your model is one of the $c_i$, but $d$ (which names an element of your model) is *not* any of the $c_i$, do you see how to reach a contradiction?

As for the satisfiability of every finite subtheory, notice that any finite subtheory contains only finitely many sentences of the form $d \neq c_i$. In particular, there's some $n$ so that $d = c_n$ is allowed (since there's $\omega$ many such constants). Do you see how this gets you out of the predicament from the previous part?

---

I hope this helps ^_^